# In apache how to require IP plus user to access URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

In apache2 with ubuntu how to configure a location(URL) that particular IP + user can only access. I use below code but it will always ask username and password even my ip does not match. if my ip does not match then it should block(403) my request and if my ip match then ask for username and password and if username and password are valid then after user can access that location(URL), otherwise block(403) that location(URL).

`<Location /secret-url/>
    Require ip <IPV4>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require user <USERNAME>
</Location>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
<Location /secret-url/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    <RequireAll>
      Require ip <IPV4>
      Require user <USERNAME>
    </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

If you want to allow request that either ip are valid or user/password are valid then change `<RequireAll>` to `<RequireAny>`:

```
<Location /secret-url/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    <RequireAny>
      Require ip <IPV4>
      Require user <USERNAME>
    </RequireAny>
</Location>
```